# MySQL - Automate a view update

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if it is possible to create an SQL function that will automatically update my View and add to it new tables in my DB.

My DB consist of multiple tables (same data structure) and are named as follow "MM_DD", now I would like to create a VIEW that joins all this data ( pretty simple , see query below) but I wish to automate the process so every time a new table is added the view  will update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `viewTable` AS
select *,
        md5(CONCAT(`columnA`,`columnB`)) AS myPK_id
  from `05_06`
 union all
select  *,
        md5(CONCAT(`columnA`,`columnB`)) AS myPK_id
  from `05_08`

  ect...
```

What I am doing at the moment is using PHP every time a table is added. It loops through the tables and create / update the view.

```
select * from information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%05%'
```

Now that I have an array of table names -> create my Query string -> replace view...

Is this possible to do this in SQL?
If so, what is the correct approach?

Comment: better idea. don't do silly things like create multiple tables that store the same thing.

Comment: I agree one table is better to maintain, but what about duplicate PK ? 90% of the data is the same across table.. Is this silly? If I were to join them into one table and just do a regular insert then I should include the time-stamp column with the PK, as it is the only way to differentiate them.. The idea is to have a snapshot of certain scrapped data at a certain time(here day/month..)..

Comment: @pala_ we were all inexperienced once. Kindness is good.  Awena, sometimes it's helpful on SO to explain what you're trying to, not just how you're trying to do it.

Comment: @OllieJones It's ok I know it is a silly question.. I'll do my best in the next questions.

Comment: Sorry to push back, but the ONLY silly question is the one you didn't ask.

Comment: @OllieJones that _was_ the kind version of my actual opinion on splitting tables by date.

Comment: @awena there is no problem including the timestamp in the primary key. you might even want to look into partitioning your tables by month or whatever your table separation criteria is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a stored procedure to rebuild your view. You'll need to use what MySQL internally calls "prepared statements" so you can use string manipulation.

You'll still use your `SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables` query to drive this stored procedure.

Once you get this working, you can embed it in a mySQL event, and arrange to run it automatically.  For example, you could run it at the same time late at night.

Or, you can invoke the stored procedure immediately after you create one of these tables.

Comment: Thank you this is interesting, I will look into 'prepared statements' and how to do it.

Comment: If you're going to that route, I would suggest a stored procedure that returns the data without bothering to create a view at all.

Comment: @TheVedge well noted. This is all new to me, I need to start my research. Thanks